# Can't create snapshot for AWS ElastiCache(redis) - node: cache.t2.*

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, snapshot, amazon-elasticache

I successfully created the ElastiCache (Redis) and already used it for a while.
Now I plan to add a backup schedule.
I tried to create Snapshot but my cluster is not show in the list.

Do you have any idea or suggestion about this case?
Engine:   redis
Zone:     ap-northeast-1c
CacheNodeType:   cache.t2.medium

Thanks,

PS. 
 
1. I tried to follow this [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/Snapshots.Manual.html), but it's not work. 
2. Sorry to post here... I cannot post in aws forum due to their policy for new user....

Comment: Read the constraints section here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/Snapshots.html

Comment: I see!! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry...It has already been written in the Constraint.

```
**Constraints**
At this time, backup and restore is supported only for clusters running on Redis.
Backup and restore is not supported on cache.t1.micro or cache.t2.* cache nodes. All other cache node types are supported.
During any contiguous 24-hour period, you can create no more than 20 manual backups per cluster.
```